# How to pointing variable that has ambiguous name in Kotlin? (this, label or using something else)

Tags: kotlin

How can I point the right variable in Kotlin using 'this' or 'label'?

I have created a code as below. The tricky part is in `apply` . What I need is to assign `roles` from `UserService` to `roles` in new instance of `User`.

```
data class User(
    var userId: String? = "",
    var roles: List<String> = emptyList()
)

class UserService {

    fun getUser() = User("test_user").apply { roles = roles.asList() }

    var roles: Array<String> = listOf("role1","role2").toTypedArray()

}
```

I know I can change the name `roles` in `UserService`. I wonder if it is possible to properly indicate the variable and keep the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is to switch to using `also`, which gives you the same thing without the ambiguity:

```
fun getUser() = User("test_user").also { it.roles = roles.asList() }
```

Another way is to explicitly label that the right side `roles` comes from `UserService`:

```
fun getUser() = User("test_user").apply { roles = this@UserService.roles.asList() }
```

Personally, I find the `also` method a lot easier to read, but it is subjective.

Answer (score 2):

`this@label`, in your case: `this@UserService`

Docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)

Comment: Thanks, I read this doc but i had to using the incorrect way of concatenating 'this' and 'UserService' because it didn't work. Now it works.